# I have built javafx through "ant build" in eclipse, but I get an error

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am struggling with the error on the 3rd day.
My jdk version is 18 and My javafx version is javafx-sdk-19
i'm trying build but it is error

When I run the javafx project in Eclipse, it works normally, but when I build through build.xml, the following error occurs.

[src path info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phsAU.jpg)

[build path info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26T2k.jpg)

```
module javafx_test1 {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    
    opens application to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
}
```

above code is module-info.java

```
 do-compile:
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\workspace\javafx_test1\build\build
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\workspace\javafx_test1\build\build\src
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\workspace\javafx_test1\build\build\libs
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\workspace\javafx_test1\build\build\classes
     [copy] Copying 8 files to D:\workspace\javafx_test1\build\build\libs
     [copy] Copying 5 files to D:\workspace\javafx_test1\build\build\src
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to D:\workspace\javafx_test1\build\build\classes
    [javac] D:\workspace\javafx_test1\build\build\src\module-info.java:2: error: module not found: javafx.controls
    [javac]     requires javafx.controls;
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] D:\workspace\javafx_test1\build\build\src\module-info.java:3: error: module not found: javafx.fxml
    [javac]     requires javafx.fxml;
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
D:\workspace\javafx_test1\build\build.xml:101: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

above code is error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="javafx_test1" default="do-deploy" basedir="."  xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
<target name="init-fx-tasks">
    <path id="fxant">
        <filelist>
            <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
            <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
        </filelist>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
        classpathref="fxant"/>
</target>
<target name="setup-staging-area">
    <delete dir="externalLibs" />
    <delete dir="project" />
    <delete dir="projectRefs" />

    <mkdir dir="externalLibs" />

    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="C:\test\javafx-sdk-19\lib">
            <filename name="javafx.controls.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="C:\test\javafx-sdk-19\lib">
            <filename name="javafx.swing.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="C:\test\javafx-sdk-19\lib">
            <filename name="javafx.base.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="C:\test\javafx-sdk-19\lib">
            <filename name="javafx-swt.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="C:\test\javafx-sdk-19\lib">
            <filename name="javafx.graphics.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="C:\test\javafx-sdk-19\lib">
            <filename name="javafx.media.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="C:\test\javafx-sdk-19\lib">
            <filename name="javafx.web.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="C:\test\javafx-sdk-19\lib">
            <filename name="javafx.fxml.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="project" />
    <copy todir="project">
        <fileset dir="D:\workspace\javafx_test1">
            <include name="src/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="projectRefs" />
</target>
<target name='do-compile'>
    <delete dir="build" />
    <mkdir dir="build/src" />
    <mkdir dir="build/libs" />
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />

    <!-- Copy project-libs references -->
    <copy todir="build/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="javafx-swt.jar"/>
            <include name="javafx.fxml.jar"/>
            <include name="javafx.swing.jar"/>
            <include name="javafx.graphics.jar"/>
            <include name="javafx.base.jar"/>
            <include name="javafx.web.jar"/>
            <include name="javafx.controls.jar"/>
            <include name="javafx.media.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Copy project references -->

    <!-- Copy project sources itself -->
    <copy todir="build/src">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <javac includeantruntime="false" source="18" target="18" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="UTF-8">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="build/libs">
                <include name="javafx-swt.jar"/>
                                <include name="javafx.fxml.jar"/>
                                <include name="javafx.swing.jar"/>
                                <include name="javafx.graphics.jar"/>
                                <include name="javafx.base.jar"/>
                                <include name="javafx.web.jar"/>
                                <include name="javafx.controls.jar"/>
                                <include name="javafx.media.jar"/>
            </fileset>
            <filelist>
                <file name="C:\test\jdk-18.0.2.1\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
            </filelist>
        </classpath>
    
    </javac>

    <!-- Copy over none Java-Files -->
    <copy todir="build/classes">
    <fileset dir="project/src">
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    </copy>


</target>
<target name="do-deploy" depends="setup-staging-area, do-compile, init-fx-tasks">
    <delete file="dist"/>
    <delete file="deploy" />

    <mkdir dir="dist" />
    <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />

    <copy todir="dist/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>


    <fx:resources id="appRes">
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="javafx_test1.jar"/>
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
    </fx:resources>

    <fx:application id="fxApplication"
        name="test34345"
        mainClass="application.Main"
    />

    <mkdir dir="build/classes/META-INF" />



    <fx:jar destfile="dist/javafx_test1.jar">
        <fx:application refid="fxApplication"/>
        <fileset dir="build/classes">
        </fileset>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="makery.ch"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="test34345"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0"/>
            <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>
        </manifest>
    </fx:jar>


    <mkdir dir="deploy" />
    <!-- Need to use ${basedir} because somehow the ant task is calculating the directory differently -->
    <fx:deploy
        embedJNLP="false"
        extension="false"
        includeDT="false"
        offlineAllowed="true"
        outdir="${basedir}/deploy"
        outfile="javafx_test1" nativeBundles="exe"
        updatemode="background" >

        <fx:platform basedir="${java.home}"/>
        <fx:info title="javafx_test1" vendor="makery.ch"/>

        <fx:application refId="fxApplication"/>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
    </fx:deploy>


</target>
```

above code is build.xml

Comment: no screenshots of plain text please (c&p the error message)

Comment: This simply is not going to work at all.  `ant-javafx.jar` and `jfxrt.jar` are obsolete and don't exist in modern JavaFX versions.  `javafx.graphics.jar`, etc. are not names of JavaFX jars. Instead, follow the instructions at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/.  Use a modern build tool (I suggest Maven).